# Получить массив чисел, сумма которого не больше n

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Итак, привет.

Недавно задумался над функцией которая бы или разбивала число на несколько рандомных слагаемых (К примеру 5), сумма которых бы не превышала первично заданное число (n).

Или генерировала массив с несколькими числами (К примеру 5-ю), сумма которых бы не превышала первично заданное число (n). Т.е. массив из 5-ти чисел, сумма которых не должна превышать 10.

Решил пойти по второму пути, так как по первому вообще ничего не приходило в голову, и вот создал скрипт который бы генерировал массив, но тут загвоздка.

А именно: Как ограничить сумму чисел(Элементов) массива до числа n (К примеру 10), чтобы при этом элементов  в массиве было минимум 5 штук,и не более 5-ти.

Загвоздка в том, что не понимаю как вообще выполняется первая функция что я описал.

Мне бы объяснение и пример любой рабочей функции, хоть первой, хоть второй.
А то хоть убей не могу понять как происходит сие действо, прошу вашей помощи

Код прилагаю:

```js
let n = 10,
    numbers = [],
    sum = 0;

    function randomNum(min, max) {
        let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min +1);
        rand = Math.round(rand);
        writeArr(rand);
    }
    function writeArr(rand) {
        numbersLength = numbers.length;
        numbers[numbersLength] = rand;
        countArr();
        // console.log(numbersLength);
        // console.log(numbers)
        // console.log(countWork)
    }
    function countArr() {
      sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sum += numbers[i];
        }
        // if (sum > 11) {
        //   numbers = [];
        //   // for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) randomNum(1, n);
        //   if (numbersLength < 5) {
        //     // return
        //   }
        // }
        console.log(numbers)
        console.log(sum)
        if (numbers.length >= 5) {
            clearArr();
        }
    }
    function clearArr() {
      sum = 0;
      numbers = [];
    }
// for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) randomNum(1, n);

function startScript() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) randomNum(1, n);
}

const start = document.querySelector('.Start');

start.addEventListener('click', startScript)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="Start">Start</button>   
 <script async src="partition.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Какая у Вас цель? Где это будет применяться?

Comment: Сумма итоговая, получается по заданию, должна тоже быть случайной. Тогда алгоритм может быть таким. 1) Генерируем итоговую сумму в заданном диапазоне как rand(min, max); 2) Генерируем заданное количество случайных чисел в диапазоне (0, 1); 3) Нормализуем сумму набора случайных чисел к посчитанной случайной сумме (возможно, с приведением к целому).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

const getRandomInt = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  

const getNumComponents = num => {
  const components = [];
  let currentSum = 0;
  
  for(let i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    const component = getRandomInt(1, num - currentSum - i);
    components.push(component);
    currentSum += component;
  }
  
  return components;
};

input.onchange = e => {
  const {value} = e.target;
  if(!value) {
    return;
  }

  const num = parseInt(value, 10);
  if(isNaN(num)) {
    return alert('Не число');
  }
  
  if (num < 5) {
    return alert('Число слишком маленькое');
  }
  
  const result = getNumComponents(num);
  console.info(result, result.reduce((a, r) => r += a, 0));
};
```

```html
<input id='input' placeholder='Введите число'><br>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Алгоритм такой:
На каждом шагу мы берем число, вычитаем из него уже имеющуюся сумму + номер шага.
Зачем нужно вычитать номер шага? Это гарантирует, что для каждого минимальное возможное число равно 1, так мы избавляем то нулей. 
*Например*: num = 10

```
1 шаг - Случайное число будет между [1 и 6] ( 10 - 0 - 4 ) (выпало) => 1
2 шаг - Случайное число будет между [1 и 6] ( 10 - 1 - 3 ) => 5
3 шаг - Случайное число будет между [1 и 2] ( 10 - 6 - 2 ) => 1
4 шаг - Случайное число будет между [1 и 2] ( 10 - 7 - 1 ) => 2
5 шаг - Случайное число будет между [1 и 1] ( 10 - 9 - 0 ) => 1
```

Это гарантирует что в сумме не будет нулей

При маленьких числах часто будет 0 попадаться, если хотите его убрать, то тогда с низу будет ограничение числа равное 5 ( попробуйте сами реализовать )

Comment: Ему не надо попадать в сумму, ему надо не превысить её.

Comment: Верно излагаете.

Comment: @ЛебедевАртем это можно было сделать, поправив одну строчку. Причем двумя разными способами

Comment: Прошу прощения, в скором времени проверю, если это действительно так, то отмечу ваш ответ как верный

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то строчка "result.reduce((a, r) => r += a, 0)"
Означает: Применение функции к каждому элементу массива, сводя его к одному значению? От a до ,присваиваем r со сложением a. Немного не понял, для чего здесь 0?

Comment: 0 это начальное значение, сама строчка не нужна, она просто выводит сумму получившихся чисел, что бы показать, что она не больше изначального числа

Comment: @ThisMan, речь ведь идет о строчке, const component = getRandomInt(1, num - currentSum - i); верно?

Comment: А как сделать его чтобы он точно попадал в число? Стало интересно

Comment: мой первый вариант точно попадал в число... но вас он почему то не устроил